# Use HTML with dynamic fields to render response in Express Node JS framework

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am able to route to simple html file without using Jade by simply replacing this code under routes folder index.js file with this one below:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../views') });
```

});

HTML code:

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Hi!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i replace "Hi!" static string with a similar #{myvalue} tag of Jade?
For example i would like to add in the p tag the current datetime.
This file maybe not be .html as it is static, but .js or anything. I am looking something like .php files do.
I am new to express and node.js and i am asking just to know if it is possible not to use jade style but html style for my views?

Comment: why not use html? :p

Comment: html is static, you can use javascript in `html`.

Comment: i described it a bit wrong, I will edit the question. I do not mean .html files but a file that can use #{value} using html tags. Like php does...

Comment: Why not use a templating system that's a bit closer to HTML then? Handlebars is much more like HTML than Jade is. I don't really like Jade because it differs too much from HTML.

Comment: There's good examples of what Handlebars looks like at http://handlebarsjs.com/ and it sounds like exactly what you're after - you can use your regular HTML tags and just use Handlebars for variables and flow control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML in Jade

**`index.jade`:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>#{myvalue}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Just render it as Jade

```
res.render('index.jade');
```

***Caveat*:** Indentation will throw errors. Because of the obvious reason that indentation is interpreted by jade as tags' scopes.

So **this won't work**:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>#{myvalue}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**A solution** to this could be use a parent tag with a [trailing dot operator](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text), so that everything inside of it is treated as plain text (i.e. HTML if you're using tags). So **this will work**:

```
html.
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>#{myvalue}</p>
    </body>
```